Need some advice with usage of more then two speakers!
I have a problem to get full surround when playing on YouTube or Nettflix in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
When I test it on the sound-setting it come sound in every speaker.
The hardware:
-NVIDIA T400 that are made for use with 4k movie.
-Pioneer 7.1 surround receiver.
The computer is connected to the receiver wit HDMI cable and the tv to one of the output. This has always worked fine before but seams like there are an missing link to get sound in al the speakers.
Is there a quick-fix for this problem?
